# Inserting data from an SqlLite3 database into a QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, qtsql

I'm building a GUI for our testing platform have been instructed the user should be able select tests from a table to run. I'm having issues getting the data into the table itself. I can fetch the data fine, but cannot populate the `QTableWidget`

This is a sample of the data I'm trying to populate the table with

```
Id | Test name    | Owner | Script source
---|-----------   |-------|--------------
 1 | Login        |  1    | test_login_s
 2 | Logout       |  1    | test_logout_s
 3 | User > Edit  |  1    | test_user_edit_s
```

Initially, I tried to use the `sqlite3` package to achieve this task, but reading has led me to the `QtSQL` package, which seems easier to use with the given task.

Here's my latest attempt at implimentation using `QtSQL`.

```
def load_data(self):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM Tests''')
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in range(len(rows)):
        for column in range(len(rows[row])):
            self.tblTests.setItem(row, column, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(rows[row][column]))
```

This reults in `None` being returned from `self.tblTests.setItem(row, column, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(rows[row][column]))`.

I have also tried the following approach

```
    for row, key in enumerate(rows):
        for column, data in enumerate(rows[row]):
            self.tblTests.setItem(row, column, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
```

In this case, `data` returns

```
1
Login
1
test_login_s
2
Logout
1
test_logout_s
3
User > Edit
1
test_user_edit_s
```

This seems like it's on the right track. It still, however, does not populate `tblTests`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After attempting to debug the above code, and seeing that `data` returned values, I thought something must be off.

After peeking through the `setupUI()` function, I came across the line `self.tblTests.setColumnCount(0)`. Intitially, I had thought this line was redundant due to the `setItem()` call, but decided to leave it in the code for the sake of debugging.

I took a stab in the dark, and set `self.tblTests.setColumnCount(0)` to 4, and it now works as intended.

I saw nothing in the documentation to suggest `setColumnCount` needs to be entered manually when reading the documentation.

Hopefully this helps somebody else too!

Comment: Ah, okay. Editing the answer